# Find all primes $p$ and $q$ such that $p^2+1 | 2003^q+1$ and $q^2+1 |2003^p+1$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math, divisibility

> Find all primes $p$ and $q$ such that $p^2+1 | 2003^q+1$ and $q^2+1 |2003^p+1$.

If $$p=2$$
then $$p^2+1=5$$
we have $$2003^q+1\equiv 0 [5]$$
$$2003^{2q}-1\equiv 0 [5]$$
let $o_{5}(2003)$ be the order of $2003$ modulo $5$

we have $$o_{5}(2003) |2q$$
$$2003\equiv 3[5]$$
and $$3^4\equiv 1[5]$$
 $$o_{5}(2003)=4$$
so $$2 |q$$
Hence $$q=2$$
So $$(p,q)=(2,2)$$
Let's assume that $$(p,q)\neq(2,2)$$
I think we will use p-adic valuation. But I don't know how .
Moreover , I m sure that there are no other solutions . But I need to prove it .

Comment: Your approach is very roundabout... simply note that $2003^q+1\equiv0\pmod{5}$ implies that $q\equiv2\pmod{4}$, and hence because $q$ is prime $q=2$.

Comment: What I found so far: $p \neq 5$ because $2003^q+1$ is never multiple of $13$. $p \neq 11$ because in order to $2003^q+1$ is multiple of $61$, $q$ must be multiple of $30$.

Comment: Now the smallest unchecked candidate $19$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [solution](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q9h1132883p5273360) that i found in art of problem solving
[image]

Comment: Very nice solution! A link to the source seems appropriate.